# "GLX 1.3 or later is required" for Chrome. Only Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Looked around for an answer but nothing clear so far. I installed the Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem for Windows 10 and it was working form until about last week. Then only Chrome started giving me this issue. I display it with xming server. Firefox works fine. I need both to test web automation.

```
[32090:32110:1126/093011.515928:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
[32128:32128:1126/093012.076678:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(429)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[32128:32128:1126/093012.076912:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(147)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[32128:32128:1126/093012.081978:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(184)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[32090:32211:1126/093012.762055:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/isantacruz/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
--2018-11-26 09:30:12--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.15.206, 2607:f8b0:4008:80e::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.15.206|:443... 
(google-chrome:32090): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 09:30:13.135: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport disabled for address disabled:
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: /dev/fd/4

Crash dump id: c93b777f804e8303

     0K                                Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/isantacruz/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
--2018-11-26 09:30:13--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 172.217.8.142, 2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|172.217.8.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: /dev/fd/4

Crash dump id: 3958a83a9feea8d4
```

Chrome opens, but its just a white window.

Comment: Which Windows Xserver are you using (cygwin? Xming? MobaXterm?)

Comment: Damn, didn't got any email that this got a response. I'm still getting this error on a new clean install. Using Xming. I got around it using firefox but never for chrome to work.